# Unable to set recyclerview below cardview

Tags: android

I am trying to set my recyclerview under the cardview but i don t know exactly the solution:

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rel"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_competition"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/X"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_team1"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="start"
                        android:src="@drawable/placemahdi"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"

                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name_team1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textAlignment="center"/>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/linear_team2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image_team2"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:src="@drawable/placemahdi"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name_team2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />



                </LinearLayout>



                <TextView
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="توقع النتيجة"
                    android:id="@+id/divide"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />




                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_vote0"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_forwardplus"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/between"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/between" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_vote1"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_backplus"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/between"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_vote1"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_vote1"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_vote1"
                  />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_vote2"
                    android:text="X"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_vote01"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_backplus"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/between1"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/between1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_vote10"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_forwardplus"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/between1"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_vote10"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_vote10"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button_vote10"/>


            </RelativeLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/re2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layoutDirection="ltr">


        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_vote"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have tried to set the "re2" relativelayout gravity to center it works on many android phones but on smaller screen some of  recyclerview parts hide under the cardview.

I have tried also setting the gravity to bottom so it starts from bottom with marginbottom=15dp but also there s a lot of blank spaces between recyclerview and cardview

This is a screenshot for the layout:

[image]

How can i set the recyclerview to start directly below the cardview ?

Comment: Are you using `CoordinatorLayout` for a specific reason?

Comment: No by default i used it @RohanStark

Comment: Please see my answer. And you can read more about `LinearLayout` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your views are overlapping is because of the `CoordinatorLayout`. `CoordinatorLayout` extends a `FrameLayout`. These are designed to place views that overlap each other.

What you need is a `ListView`. It is specifically designed to show children in lists in the order that they are added in the XML file. So, if your `CoordinatorLayout` doesn't serve any other purpose, then change it to a `LinearLayout`. Something like the following :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
      .
      .
      .
      .

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rohan it worked perfectly i didn t know the whole issue was about CoordinatorLayout .I have understood it now

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help